# How to upgrade Azure ACS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I see that it's possible to upgrade an AKS cluster with `az aks upgrade`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-cluster

I see that it's possible to upgrade a kubernetes cluster that has been created with acs-engine with `acs-engine upgrade`: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/tree/master/examples/k8s-upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade a kubernetes cluster that has been created with ACS?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to upgrade a kubernetes cluster that has been created
>   with ACS?

For now, there is no way to upgrade k8s version directly.

Since ACS is basically an IaaS offering you could perform the upgrade [**manually**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm-upgrade-1-7/).

Here a similar [case](https://github.com/colemickens/azure-kubernetes-status/issues/15) about you, please refer to it.